# Почему g++-10 не может использовать ключевые слова связанные с корутинами, хотя 20 стандарт включен и необходимый флаг выставлен?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, coroutine, c++20

Я попытался использовать ключевые слова из с++20 связанные с корутинами, но компилятор выдает ошибку

> Std::experimental::coroutine_traits type was not found; include
> <experimental/coroutine> before defining a coroutine

Несмотря на то, что в cmake указан 20 стандарт и выставлен необходимый флаг, заголовок `<coroutine>`тоже без проблем подключается.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -pthread -fcoroutines")
```

Я использую компилятор g++-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить возникшую проблему ???

Comment: ну так компилятор говорит, используйте `<experimental/coroutine>` вместо/вместе `<coroutine>`

Comment: проблема в том что при попытке подключения `experimental/coroutine file not found`, да и g++-10 вроде поддерживает корутины уже как часть стандарта. @KoVadim

Comment: `Std::experimental::coroutine_traits` таки может быть стоит убрать experimental из namespace? Раз уж вы используете не его, а `<coroutine>`

Comment: @vp_arth, а как это сделать, насколько я знаю, при использовании ключевых слов не нужно указывать namespace. Собственно Std::experimental я нигде и ну указывал, тот путь используется по умолчанию

Comment: Ну не знаю, можете [у меня на github](https://github.com/vpArth/cpp20) глянуть. Я там щупал корутины пару месяцев назад) Скорее всего, какой-нибудь coroutine_handle/traits у вас берётся из std::experimental